# Why isn't this "else" statement working?

Tags: java

***edited***

Here's the whole program.  I wrapped the char in a Character wrapper to use .equals() and fixed the index issue, and replaced the constants with literals.  The program compiles and runs fine, tells you if the symbols are matched, but still skips that "else" statement when there is an unmatched symbol:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;


public class Exercise22_11 {

/**
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**for command line argument*/

        if(args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("You didn't enter an argument dummy!");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        String fileString = "";

        /**Open the file and read it*/

        try{    
            File myOutFile = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(myOutFile);
            while (input.hasNext()){
        fileString += input.next();
            }

        }//try

        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("Sorry that file is not found " + e);
        }//catch

        /**Build the list of characters from file*/

        char[] charArray = new char[fileString.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < fileString.length(); i++) {
            charArray[i] = fileString.charAt(i);
        }//for building charArray

        /**Create a stack to manipulate grouping symbols*/

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        /**Pushes grouping symbols into stack and pops them when they correspond*/

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            Character temp = new Character(charArray[i]);

            if (temp.equals('{') || temp.equals('(') || temp.equals('[')) {
                stack.push(temp);
            }   else if (temp.equals('}') || temp.equals(')') || temp.equals(']')) {
                if (temp.equals('}') && stack.peek().equals('{')){
                    stack.pop();
                }   else if (temp.equals(')') && stack.peek().equals('(')) {
                    stack.pop();
                }   else if (temp.equals(']') && stack.peek().equals('[')) {
                    stack.pop();
                }   else {
                    System.out.println("There is a mistake at index: " + i);
                    System.out.println("\nHere's the code (the error is in the middle):\n");
                    for(int j = i - 20; j <= i + 20; j++) {
                        System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }

        }//for

        /**Inform user of result*/

        if (stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations!  Your grouping symbols are matched!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry.  Please fix your program.");
        }



}//main



}//class
```

The final "else" statement is skipped at run time when there is an error.

The assignment was to write a program using a list or collection that checks if the grouping symbols in a program are overlapped. The file should be entered as a command line argument.

Here's what I asked the professor (no answer yet):

1. Why can't I create a scanner to read every character from the .txt(or .java) file?  I tried using a delimiter of "" (no space) to avoid the RIDICULOUS String to Char[] to manipulation with the stack().
2. What's with the friggin' "else" statement?

Thanks!

Comment: The `ONE`, `TWO` etc. constants are only confusing things. Statement `temp == SIX && stack.peek().equals(FIVE)` makes absolutely no sense. `temp == ']' && stack.peek().equals('[')` would be much easier to read. If you named the constants logically, i.e. `OPEN_SQUARE_BRACKET` and `CLOSE_SQUARE_BRACKET`, it would be readable, but not any more than literals and literals are shorter.

Comment: Didn't you want to print the _index_, i.e. `i`?

Comment: Why are you sometimes using `==` and sometimes `Object.equals`?

Comment: @JanHudec: Honestly, I was pressed for time and concentrating very hard on figuring out the solution to the problem.  I needed some distance from the literals to work it out (if that makes sense) and typing the apostrophes was getting annoying.  This was a short one-off - I would change everything to literals when finished.

Comment: @JanHudec: You are correct about the index.  The first draft was complex with the final else statement displaying the problem character, index and a snippet of the code where it happened.  I whittled it down to nothing trying to figure out why it isn't printing.

Comment: @JanHudec: char temp is a primitive, I can't use .equals().  You're saying wrap it in a Character wrapper?

Comment: @JanHudec Is the like **skipped** at runtime, or simply never reached?  If it's the latter, it might help if you post the contents of your char[].

Comment: I have one suggestion. @MayNotBe, can you post complete, runnable, code into [ideone](http://ideone.com) (you have to switch language to Java, default is C++) and post the link? Than there will be no confusion over what it actually does and the error will hopefully be obvious.

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code and search/replaced the confusing constants with the literals as they should be. It worked fine when I tried it. I strongly suspect you have flubbed your constants at some point. It would be very helpful if you would show where you define those constants. And your stack object too, while you're at it. (Had I the rep this would be a comment instead of an answer; I'll edit this into a more coherent answer if more information is posted.)

Comment: Are you working in Eclipse/NetBeans/IDEA? This is the kind of thing that stepping through with a debugger, line by line, would be immensely helpful for.

Comment: @JanHudec: I edited the OP with the whole program and removed the embarrassing constants.  I'll check out ideone.

Comment: @KChaloux: I'm working in Eclipse and I haven't ever worked with the debugger.  That's on my list of "Things to Learn"!

Comment: I updated the OP with the whole program.  That else is still skipped for me.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @MayNotBe Now's the time to learn it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If this print statement is for debugging, then it shouldn't be placed inside an `else`. You want your mistake to go inside one of the else-ifs to be fixed (or popped), **and then** print *where the mistake was found*. Get rid of that else statement. Make it

```
}   else if (temp == SIX && stack.peek().equals(FIVE)) {
                    stack.pop();
                }   
    System.out.println("There is a mistake at index: " + charArray[i]); //it will work now
```

Comment: It writes the error message for all elements even there is no mistake.

Comment: How would an else be executed if an else-if (on the same level) is already executed?

Comment: System.out.println("There is a mistake at index: " + charArray[i]); is not in an else statement in your answer. 

It will be executed after statements.

Comment: I agree with @blank.  You took the "else" away so now it prints every time temp == TWO, FOUR or SIX, regardless.

Well ... at least it would print.  Still can't figure out why it's not.